# Simple way allow users different subscriptions in stripe (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, stripe-payments

The way I have my Stripe payment set up now it is a single monthly fee of $10. I want to create another fee of $25 that lets my users use the site for three months. I know how to create a customer, that is not my problem. I want the user to be able to click a link that would take them to either payment amount, or a simple way to let them choose in the registration page.

This is my provider (BillingServiceProvider.php):

```
<?php namespace Acme\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class BillingServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind('Acme\Billing\BillingInterface', 'Acme\Billing\StripeBilling');
}
}
```

The amount charged is declared in StripeBilling:

```
class StripeBilling implements BillingInterface {

public function __construct()
{
    Stripe::setApiKey(Config::get('stripe.secret_key'));
}

public function charge(array $data)
{
    try
    {
        return Stripe_Charge::create([
            'amount' => 1000, // $10
            'currency' => 'usd',
            'card' => $data['token'],
            'description' => $data['email']
        ]);

    }
}
}
```

BillingInterface has one function: `charge(array $data)`

I feel like I should make another file almost identical to StripeBilling with a different amount but I don't know how to access it in the provider.

Any help is appreciated, let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: Is there a reason I'm not catching why you can't just send that amount to this function?

Comment: Is there a good way to do that without allowing a user to change the source code and manipulate how much they pay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is setup a table of subscription_types which would contain all your subscription types.  It would be a simple table, probably just an `id`, `name`, and `amount` would be bare minimum.  Then you can create your model for this...  The users function here isn't too important.  You really just need the class.

```
// models/SubscriptionType.php
class SubscriptionType extends Eloquent 
{
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('User');
    }
}
```

Then to connect this table to your users, you can update your users table to also include a `subscription_type_id` and a `subscription_status` column.  Then when your user picks a subscription they want to go with, you set that column.

```
$subscription = Subscription::find($idOfSubscriptionTheyWant);
Auth::user()->subscription()->associate($subscription);
```

Now that we know the user's desired subscription, during checkout, we know exactly how much to charge them...

```
$biller = App::make('Acme\Billing\BillingInterface');
$success = $biller->charge($data, Auth::user()->subscription->amount);
if($success) {
     $user = Auth::user();
     $user->subscription_status = 1;
     $user->save();
}
```

Lastly....

```
// Modify your charge function to something like this... 
public function charge(array $data, $amount)
{
    try
    {
        return Stripe_Charge::create([
            'amount' => $amount,
            'currency' => 'usd',
            'card' => $data['token'],
            'description' => $data['email']
        ]);

    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry it took me a while to get back but worked perfectly, Thank you!